# how to change url dynamically when using $ngResource in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

Here is my code

```
Const User = $resource('/user/:id', {},
{
    'query': {
        method: 'GET',
        url:'/user/phone/:phone/name/:name',
        isArray: true
    }
});
```

When I type:

```
User.query({name: Li});
User.query({phone: 123456});
```

Http request will be:

```
get /user/phone/name/Li
get /user/phone/123456/name
```

But I hope it to be:

```
get /user/name/Li
get /user/phone/123456
```

Could someone tell me how to remove part substring in url dynamically? Must I use $http to generate different url respectively?

My English is poor. Thanks!

Comment: Try: `url:'/user/:A/:B'` and then `User.query({A: phone, B: 123456});` will hopefully become `get /user/phone/123456` .. just an observation, I have not tested

Comment: It's true, but it's not graceful. If so, I have to add more parameters to use it.

Comment: I have a file uploader that uses `$resource` where I use two parameters, looks like this `Item.upload({id: Id, filename: fileName}` have had zero problems